# What is the suitable IDE to Mule 4.3 Kernel (CE)

Tags: ide, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

AnypointStudio 7.9 is just supporting for Mule 4.3 EE. Can anyone suggest a suitable IDE to Mule 4.3 Kernel (CE)?

Answer (score 0):

Mule Kernel specifically targets no graphical IDE:

> Download if you are:
>
> ```
> Comfortable editing XML directly
> Not looking for a graphical modeling and testing environment
> Have already created and tested a Mule application and you need to deploy in a separate Mule standalone runtime
> ```

https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime

Try using a good text editor with XML and Maven support. Visual Studio Code is very good and has support for both.